# Navigation bar button not showing

Tags: iphone, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

When try to add a navigation button on left and right side , its not showing?is this is the code i used for, Whats wrong with this?

this is how i added the navigation bar in in appdelegate,

```
  UIViewController *viewController1 = [[logyFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"logyFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *viewController2 = [[logySecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"logySecondViewController" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *viewController3 = [[record alloc] initWithNibName:@"record" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *viewController4 = [[searchview alloc] initWithNibName:@"searchview" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *viewController5 = [[profilde alloc] initWithNibName:@"profilde" bundle:nil];
 self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, viewController5];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;

[navigationController.navigationBar setAlpha:0.8f];
 [self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];





 button4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f)];
 [button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [button4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"del.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 UIBarButtonItem *random1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button4];
 self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=random1;
```

please help.

Comment: use this line [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:random1];

Comment: by the way, from Apples Documentation
[[ 
- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController

((rootViewController))
The view controller that resides at the bottom of the navigation stack. This object cannot be an instance of the UITabBarController class.
]] 

Look at this linnk : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: upload screenshot of your navigation bar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your code 
just check your image or try with a rounded rect image to test

```
UIButton* button4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f)];
[button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *random1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button4];
```

and use 
    `self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem=random1;`
instead of
    `self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=random1;`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the following line :

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=random1;
```

Simply use

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=random1;
```

Comment: yeah i tried this also but it doesn showing the button..pls help me

Comment: If your app has more than a single navigation bar, then are you sure that the correct navigation bar is visible?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button4 =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"del.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f)]];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button4] autorelease];
```

use same method for leftBarButtonItem.Hope it works for you.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work for you...

```
UIButton *button4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f)];
[button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"del.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *random1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button4];
[button4 release];

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:random1];
[random1 release];
```

Comment: No its not working, i updated the code in in question pls check

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextToPhoneAuth)];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBtnItem
```

Answer (score 0):

please check that your navigation bar is provided hidden property and try with default back button once & let us know is it working or not.