# Custom leftBarButtonItem not showing in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

i'm trying to add custom lefBarButton in navigation item
but it not showing anything 
i tried these answers

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564480/custom-leftbarbuttonitem-not-showed-in-ios-11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyusv.png)

[navigation bar button not showing in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244492/navigation-bar-button-not-showing-in-swift-3)

[navigation bar button and items not showing in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357298/navigation-bar-button-and-items-not-showing-in-swift-3)

[Navigation bar button not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707634/navigation-bar-button-not-showing)

[Bar button item not shown in navigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696523/bar-button-item-not-shown-in-navigationbar)

[Navigation bar not showing iOS swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689255/navigation-bar-not-showing-ios-swift)

[Swift 3 - Why is my Navigation Bar not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407806/swift-3-why-is-my-navigation-bar-not-showing)

[iOS 8 Swift navigation bar title, buttons not showing in tab based application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436281/ios-8-swift-navigation-bar-title-buttons-not-showing-in-tab-based-application)

segue type for my view controller is show.

here is my code

```
    let leftButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
    leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    leftButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    leftButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
    leftButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "back-icon")
    leftButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22, height: 15)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: leftButton)
```

i spend hours to fix it.
does anyone have have any idea.

[image]

here is the back button
[image]

Comment: Ummm... what does this line do `leftButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "back-icon")`? :x

Comment: this is the image i want to show on button

Comment: @RakeshaShastri i added it to question

Comment: please check if there is any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line.

```
leftButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "back-icon")
```

> [imageView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624033-imageview) is a read-only property.

If you want to set an image, you should set it like this.

```
leftButton.setImage(UIImage("back-icon"), for: .normal) // Make sure your image is actually named "back-icon"
```